# Could not Install microsoft azure authoring tools 2.7.1

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to install microsoft azure authoring tools 2.7.1 on Visual Studio 2013 using Web Platform installer. It throws error with 404 (Not found). Anyone solution ?

Here's what I found in the log -

> DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error while downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringToolsx86.msi'. Exception: System.Net.WebException: Url 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringToolsx86.msi' returned HTTP status code: 404
>   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.OpenUrlAndFollowRedirects(Uri& uri, IntPtr& hInetFile)
>   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ManagedWinInet.DownloadFile(Uri uri, String fileName, String& contentDispositionFileName)
>   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.InstallManager.WinInetDownloadInstallerFile(InstallerContext currentInstall, String& failureReason)
>   DownloadManager Warning: 0 : WinInet failure: Url 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringToolsx86.msi' returned HTTP status code: 404. Retrying download for 'Microsoft Azure Authoring Tools - 2.7.1'
>   DownloadManager Information: 0 : WebClient downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringToolsx86.msi' to: C:\Users\GXberde\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1092.tmp
>   DownloadManager Error: 0 : WebClient error while downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringToolsx86.msi'. Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)
>   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.InstallManager.WebClientDownloadInstallerFile(InstallerContext currentInstall, String& errorMessage)
>   DownloadManager Warning: 0 : WebClient failure: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.. Retrying download for 'Microsoft Azure Authoring Tools - 2.7.1'
>   DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringToolsx86.msi' to: C:\Users\GXberde\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1100.tmp
>   DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringToolsx86.msi responded with 404
>   DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
>   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
>   Via: 1.1 TMGSPAPP04
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length: 1245
>   Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 14:12:07 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   Content-Disposition: attachment

Comment: If you want, you can manually download the SDK files from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.